# Difference between すべて and ぜんぶ

Tags: word-choice

Title basically says it all. I think meanings are very close. Are they interchangeable? Are they appropriate for different contexts or situations? Can one be applied to animate objects and other can't? So far I can't figure out when to use one over the other. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the kanji, one says "all" and the other "all parts". In that sense one can distinguish them philosophically as 全て meaning "everything" (universally) and 全部 "all" (part by part).

I think you can make out that difference when looking at examples (for example on [Space ALC](http://www.alc.co.jp/): [全て](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%85%A8%E3%81%A6&ref=sa) and [全部](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%85%A8%E9%83%A8).)

For example,

> 全部あなたのせいだからね。
>   Everything is your fault.

The person is blamed for everything (every single thing) they did. Whereas,

> 全てあなたのせいだからね。

sounds like everything he did, is doing, and will do would be his fault, by default.

Universal statements, like

> 全てについて債務者が悪い。
>   He who owes, is in all the wrong.

use 全て.